# Web Font Loader does not preload correct font

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, webfonts, webfont-loader

I am using the [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to manage the loading of fonts in my code.  But I'm finding that, even when I specify a *bold* weight for a particular font, the loader is only loading the *normal* weight in advance, and only subsequently loading the bold variant.

In the html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.28/webfontloader.js"></script>
```

In the javascript:

```
var WebFontConfig = {
    "timeout": 3000,
    "classes": false,
    "custom": {
        "families": [
            "TeX Gyre Adventor:700n"
        ],
        "urls": [
            "./css/fontstuff.css"
        ]
    },
    active: function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            nowDoOtherStuff();
        }, 2500);
    }
};

WebFont.load(WebFontConfig);
```

In `fontstuff.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'TeX Gyre Adventor';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-regular.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'TeX Gyre Adventor';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-bold.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

So I am triggering my main function `nowDoOtherStuff()` off the `active` event hook, so according to my understanding by this point all the requested fonts should be available and ready... that's the point of Web Font Loader?

I put a delay of `2500ms` so that it's clear in the Network tab what resources have actually been fetched when the `active` event fires, and what I see is:

[image]

Firstly, I'm not even requesting `texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff2` so why is it being fetched at all?

Secondly, and most importantly, why is `texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.woff2` (i.e. the font I  requested) not actually fetched and ready when the `active` event fires?  It's clear from the waterfall timing (and the artificial `2500ms` delay) that the `bold` variant is only fetched *after* the `active` fires.

Why is Web Font Loader prioritizing the fetching of a font I didn't even ask for, and not fetching the font I actually want?  This is causing issues with how the subsequent code lays out the content.

BTW this issue is solved by using a `preload` (which I have only more recently discovered) in the `<head>` as follows:

```
<link rel="preload" href="./fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

However, I would like to get the Web Font Loader approach working, without having to use `preload`... I thought that the Web Font Loader was already meant to be implementing a `preload` functionality?

Comment: `I'm not even requesting texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff2` ... so what do you think `src: url('../fonts/TexGyre/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff2')` does? what happens if you swap the order of those font-face declarations?

Comment: @Bravo I thought that was just specifying where to find the `regular` font *should it be required*... rather than actually asking for it to be fetched with a network request?  I have a whole bunch of font-face declarations in my css (not just the two shown in my post), and it's not fetching all of them :-/

Comment: If I remove the `regular` declaration then the `bold` variant does indeed seem to be loaded when the `active` event fires, but surely the point of Web Font Loader is that I can specify what fonts I need dynamically, not relying on some arbitrary fixed order in a css file?  In my use case, the user can request any font group/style, which is why I'm trying to do the font fetching dynamically based on need.

Comment: Don't know, perhaps you're not using webfontloader correctly - is there any documentation available?

Comment: @Bravo "is there any documentation available?" -- in the github repo which I linked in my OP... so far as I can tell, I'm doing exactly as documented there.